# Why does Javascript isNaN function declare string negative hex values to be NaN?

Tags: javascript

Given the following example:

```
isNaN("-0x123");    // returns true , meaning is not a number <- Why?
isNaN(-0x123);      // returns false, meaning is a number
isNaN("0x123");     // returns false, meaning is a number
parseInt("-0x123"); // returns -291
```

My question: why does isNaN declares negative hex strings as NaN when other similar inputs yield more reasonable outputs?

Thanks

Comment: [`isNaN`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-isnan-number) calls [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type). `ToNumber` has predefined ruleset for number formats which allow `+/-` only for decimal number representations. And `0x123` isn't one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `isNaN()` tells you whether or not a value may be coerced to a number, it says nothing about whether there exists a function that will convert the value to a number.

You will see the same behaviour if you attempt to coerce the strings to numbers:

```
> +"-0x123"
NaN
> +(-0x123)
-291
> +"0x123"
291
```

The first case you have a string that does not match Javascript's rules for a number as that doesn't allow for a leading `-` on a hex literal, the second case you have an expression that evaluates to a number (so `0x123` negated), the third case you have a string that does match the grammar for a number.

See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3 for the exact description, but in short a string numeric literal may be an unsigned decimal literal, `+` or `-` followed by an unsigned decimal literal, or it may be a hex integer literal (and in all these cases leading and trailing whitespace is ignored). There is no option for a sign on a hex literal.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the ToNumber documentation. Would you happen to know why the designers opted to omit signed string hex literal?

Comment: @nivla12345 I can guess, but I wouldn't say I know. Perhaps they expect you to be using hex values for things like bit patterns, so if you are working with 16 bit twos-complement values you would write 0xfffe whereas -0x2 would be ambiguous.

Comment: OK, that sounds reasonable enough.

Answer (score 2):

What you are expecting is this :

```
isNaN(parseInt("-0x123")); // returns -291
```

Answer (score 1):

Because "-0x123" is treated as a string and not as a number. So

```
isNaN("-0x123");
```

will return false since there is no number. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) says:

> The isNaN() function determines whether a value is NaN or not. Note:
> coercion inside the isNaN function has interesting rules; you may
> alternatively want to use Number.
>
> .........
>
> **Confusing special-case behavior**
>
> Since the very earliest versions of the isNaN function specification,
> its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the
> argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is
> first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to
> determine whether it is NaN. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to
> numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the
> empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric
> values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the
> empty string, for example, is surely "not a number." The confusion
> stems from the fact that the term, "not a number", has a specific
> meaning for numbers represented as IEEE-754 floating-point values. The
> function should be interpreted as answering the question, "is this
> value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-754 'Not A Number'
> value?"